# Why Class can not extends Interface in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

```
interface a{
     public void getSum();

  }
public class b implements a{

     public void getDivision(){

     }
}
```

We know that but 
   why class b can not  extends interface a ? 
   What's the reason?

Comment: It doesn't extend it, it implements the interface. And this code will not compile because ``b`` does not have a ``getSum`` method.

Comment: better learn OOP Principles first.

Comment: Also this `public void getDivission();` is not a valid code for a class!!

Comment: Also also... If a function starts with `get`, it should probably return something rather than being void. It doesn't _have_ to, but it's very confusing if it doesn't.

Comment: My Question is , Why Class can not extends  interface ?

Comment: They're just different keywords (and concepts). Extending a class means you inherit all of its fields and methods. Implementing an interface means that your class will write bodies for all of the unimplemented functions.

Comment: Why Class can not extends interface ? It is how the language is designed, it is THE syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can class B not extend the interface A? What's the reason?

A class can't extend an interface because inheriting from a class (`extends`), and implementing an interface (`implements`) are two different concepts.

Hence, they use different keywords.

### Extending a class (Inheritance)

When you extend a class, you inherit all of its fields and methods.

For example:

```
public class A {
    void runInheritedMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello");    
    }
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is valid code...
        B bInstance = new B();
        bInstance.runInheritedMethod();
    }
}
```

### Implementing an interface

When you Implement an interface, your class will contain "bodies" or "implementations" for all of the unimplemented functions of said interface.

For example:

```
public interface Choppable {
    public void chop();
}

public class Wood implements Choppable {
    public void chop() {
        // Your wood-specific code here...
    }
}

public class Carrot implements Choppable {
    public void chop() {
        // Your carrot-specific code here...
    }
}
```

Both of these concepts can be used to achieve [polymorphic behaviour](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm), which is why they can cause confusion.